# Проверка занята ли память

Tags: c++, указатели, memory-management, дерево

Пишу бинарное дерево поиска, в котором может быть несколько одинаковых ключей(если быть точным, то в данном случае ключ совпадает со значением).
Хочу при удалении любого ключа (например 5) он находил и удалял все найденные ключи.
Для этого думаю написать функцию, которая рекурсивно ищет все ключи и кладет их в лит, после чего, пройдя по списку, удалить их все.

Проблема заключается в следующем:
Когда выбираются элементы со значением, то возвращаются указатели на них, соответственно если в дереве один ключ лежит раньше другого, то при удалении первого ключа рекурсивно удалится всё поддерево, следующее за ним. Соответственно, освободится память, на которую указывает второй элемент, что приведет к двойному освобождению памяти.

Наглядное представление:

```
/*  В дереве есть элемент с ключом 10, функция find_place_to_add() 
 *  возвращает указатель на этот элемент
 */ 
Tree<int>::Node* n = t1->find_place_to_add(10); 
std::cout << n->data << std::endl; // Вывод: 10

t1->clear(); // Полностью очищаем всё дерево

//Память освобождена
std::cout << n->data << std::endl; // Вывод: 10
int* i = new(n) int; 

*i = 80;
std::cout << n->data << std::endl; // Вывод: 80
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить занята ли память, на которую ссылается указатель.

Коммент заставил меня сомневаться правильно ли я вообще реализовал освобождение памяти:

```
template <typename  DataType>
void Tree<DataType>::clear() noexcept
{
    free_resources(root);

    delete root;
    root = nullptr;
}

template <typename DataType>
void Tree<DataType>::free_resources(Node* node) noexcept
{
    if(node->parent != nullptr)
    {
        if (node->data < node->parent->data)
        {
            node->parent->left = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            node->parent->right = nullptr;
        }
    }

    node->data = DataType();

    if(node->left != nullptr) free_resources(node->left);
    if(node->right != nullptr) free_resources(node->right);

    delete node->left;
    delete node->right;
}
```

Comment: Общепринятая практика: удаление/очистка контейнера инвалидирует все итераторы/ссылки/указатели на элементы контейнера. Соответственно, проверка валидности указателей ненужна - они точно неверные.

Comment: @Chorkov А как их инвалидировать? В примере видно, что указатель все равно ссылается на эту чать памяти, не смотря на то, что она была освобождена

Comment: А зачем работаете с указателями на прямую, почему бы не использовать shared?

Comment: @JK_Action Понятно, что можно, просто хотелось бы лучше вникнуть в механику обычных указателей

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg  Имея указатель (обычный) никак невозможно проверить его валидность. Под инвалидацией подразумевается что указатели становятся неверными, и отслеживать это должен программист, вызвавший очистку / удаление контейнера, но не контейнер сам по себе.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, мне непонятна проблема. Вы удаляете узел сразу со всем поддеревом? А если там не только те узлы, которые вы и так хотите удалить? По-моему, это неверный подход...

Comment: @Harry Да, вы почти всё правильно поняли. В моей реализации есть 2 функции удаления. Первая, удаляет полностью всё поддерево, начиная с данного элемента. Вторая, вырезает только элемент с заданным ключом и сохраняет поддерево. И если со второй функцией всё просто, то при удалении поддерева как раз может появиться проблема с двойным освобождением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При удалении поддерева все вообще просто - используйте рекурсию!

Сначала вы вызываете ту же функцию удаления поддерева для левого и правого потомка (если они есть), затем, уже ни о чем не волнуясь, удаляете сам узел - корень поддерева. Все узлы будут удалены, так как рекурсия будет удалят узлы, начиная от листьев и идя назад, к корню.